# Cant retrieve short description in category list view

Tags: magento

I am trying to display each products description in the category list view like this:

```
 <?php echo $_product->getDescription(); ?>
```

However, it just displays nothing. Since this works perfectly on the product page I am not quite sure where the problem is. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

Go to backend

Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes

Search for "short description" -> set "Used in Product Listing" to "Yes"

Refresh cache and Reindex

I did this for a custom attribute and I see no reason why this should not work for description/short description

Answer (score 1):

Update the `description` attribute's `use_in_product_listing` value (see catalog_eav_attribute table), either in the admin under Catalog > Manage Attributes or use an upgrade script.

The upgrade script would need to use the correct setup resource and call the following:

```
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product','description','use_in_product_listing',1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,i have used this

```
<?php echo $_product->_data['short_description']; ?>
```