# Can't get short description in category list view - despite trying suggestions

Tags: magento

Have looked at [Cant retrieve short description in category list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725604/cant-retrieve-short-description-in-category-list-view), but despite setting "Used in Product Listing" for the short_description attribute and rebuilding the indexes, and turning off the flat catalogues, `$_product->getShortDescription()` still doesn't return anything.

Is there anything else I can try, or is there some way I can debug what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Check this first,

When you are editing the list.phtml file both Grid view and List view are both created in this file. Test with a quick message in place of your getShortDescription call just to make sure you are in the right place..  If you are,  please post your code in here and I will be glad to help.

Comment: We made some progress with this, and the answer I think was quite bizarre. The product database is populated by a feed from http://www.stockinthechannel.com/, and the short_description was getting put in the catalog_product_entity_varchar table rather than catalog_product_entity_text. A quick MySQL to copy the values across  seemed to fix it, so we have an interim workaround, and I think an idea of where we need to go to get it fixed (although that remains to be confirmed).